# core five labs Filemanager add lazy loading

Tags: jquery, image-processing, coldfusion, file-manager

We have been using the [Core 5 File Manager](http://labs.corefive.com/projects/filemanager/) utility successfully for awhile now, but once our directories started accumulating 100s of images it started slowing down, drastically for our IE users. I am trying to hack in lazy loading now, but have been very unsuccessful.

Here is the block in question:

```
// Retrieve the data and generate the markup.
$.getJSON(fileConnector + '?path=' + path + '&mode=getfolder&getsizes=false&showThumbs=' + showThumbs, function(data){      
    var result = '';

    if(data){
        if(data['Code'] && data['Code'] != 0)
        {
            result = "<div style='text-align:center;color:red;'>An error occured:<br \/>" + data['Error'] + "<\/div>";
            // $.prompt(data['Error']);
        } else
        {
            var key = '';
            if($('#fileinfo').data('view') == 'grid'){
                result += '<ul id="contents" class="grid">';

                for(key in data){
                    var props = data[key]['Properties'];
                    if (props)
                    {
                        var scaledWidth = 64;
                        var actualWidth = props['Width'];
                        if(actualWidth > 1 && actualWidth < scaledWidth) scaledWidth = actualWidth;

                        result += '<li class="' + (data[key]["File Type"] == 'dir' ? 'directory':'file') + '">'+
                         '<div class="clip"><img src="' + data[key]['Preview'] + '" width="' + scaledWidth + '" alt="' + data[key]['VisiblePath'] + '" /></div><p>' + data[key]['Filename'] + '</p>';
                        if(props['Width'] && props['Width'] != '') result += '<span class="meta dimensions">' + props['Width'] + 'x' + props['Height'] + '</span>';
                        if(props['Size'] && props['Size'] != '') result += '<span class="meta size">' + props['Size'] + '</span>';
                        if(props['Date Created'] && props['Date Created'] != '') result += '<span class="meta created">' + props['Date Created'] + '</span>';
                        if(props['Date Modified'] && props['Date Modified'] != '') result += '<span class="meta modified">' + props['Date Modified'] + '</span>';
                        result += '</li>';
                    }
                }
                result += '</ul>';
                if (key=='')
                {
                    result = '<div style="margin-top:40px;text-align:center;"><em>No files found</em></div>';
                }
            } else {
                result += '<table id="contents" class="list">';
                result += '<thead><tr><th class="headerSortDown"><span>Name</span></th><th><span>Dimensions</span></th><th><span>Size</span></th><th><span>Modified</span></th></tr></thead>';
                result += '<tbody>';

                for(key in data){
                    var path = data[key]['VisiblePath'];
                    var props = data[key]['Properties'];
                    if (props)
                    {
                        result += '<tr class="' + (data[key]["File Type"] == 'dir' ? 'directory':'file') + '">';
                        result += '<td title="' + path + '">' + data[key]['Filename'] + '</td>';

                        if(props['Width'] && props['Width'] != ''){
                            result += ('<td>' + props['Width'] + 'x' + props['Height'] + '</td>');
                        } else {
                            result += '<td></td>';
                        }

                        if(props['Size'] && props['Size'] != ''){
                            result += '<td><abbr title="' + props['Size'] + '">' + formatBytes(props['Size']) + '</abbr></td>';
                        } else {
                            result += '<td></td>';
                        }

                        if(props['Date Modified'] && props['Date Modified'] != ''){
                            result += '<td>' + props['Date Modified'] + '</td>';
                        } else {
                            result += '<td></td>';
                        }

                        result += '</tr>';
                    }
                }
                if (key=='')
                {
                    result += '<tr><td colspan="4" style="text-align:center"><em>No files found</em></td></tr>';
                }

                result += '</tbody>';
                result += '</table>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        result += '<h1>Could not retrieve folder contents.</h1>';
    }

    // Add the new markup to the DOM.
    $('#fileinfo').html(result);
```

the json request hits a coldfusion function that uses the cfdirectory tag to build a struct of  data returned to the caller

```
<cffunction name="_getDirectoryInfo" returntype="array" access="private">
    <cfargument name="path" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="getsizes" type="boolean" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="filter" type="string" required="no" default="" />
    <cfset var dirlist_qry = "" />
    <cfset var data_arr = arrayNew(1) />
    <cfset var currData_struct = "" />
    <cfset var imageData_struct = "" />
    <cfset var dirPath = (arguments.path) />
    <cfset var webDirPath = _getWebPath(dirPath) />
    <cfset var displayWebPath = _getWebPath(path=dirPath, includeUploadRoot=false) />

    <cfif not DirectoryExists(dirPath)>
        <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#dirPath#"> 
        <!--- no longer required, we will auto create the directory
        <cfset returnError(translate('DIRECTORY_NOT_EXIST', dirPath)) />
        --->
    </cfif>

    <cftry>
        <cfdirectory action="list" directory="#dirPath#" name="dirlist_qry" sort="type,name" filter="#arguments.filter#" />
        <cfcatch>
            <cfset returnError(translate('UNABLE_TO_OPEN_DIRECTORY', arguments.path, cfcatch.message & " - " & cfcatch.detail)) />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

    <cfloop query="dirlist_qry"><cfif find('.', dirlist_qry.name) neq 1>
        <cfset currData_struct = structNew() />
        <cfset arrayAppend(data_arr, currData_struct) />

        <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Filename", dirlist_qry.name) />
        <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Error", "") />
        <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Code", 0) />
        <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Properties", structNew()) />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Date Created", "") />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Date Modified", "#lsdateformat(dateLastModified, 'medium')# #timeformat(dateLastModified, 'HH:mm:ss')#") />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Height", "") />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Width", "") />
        <cfif dirlist_qry.type eq "DIR">
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Path", webDirPath & dirlist_qry.name & "/") />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "VisiblePath", displayWebPath & dirlist_qry.name & "/") />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "File Type", "dir") />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Preview", request.directoryIcon) />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Size", "") />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Path", webDirPath & dirlist_qry.name) />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "VisiblePath", displayWebPath & dirlist_qry.name) />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "File Type", lCase(listlast(dirlist_qry.name, '.'))) />
            <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Size", dirlist_qry.size) />
            <cfif _isImage(dirlist_qry.name)>
                <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Preview", webDirPath & dirlist_qry.name) />
                <cfif arguments.getsizes>
                    <cfset imageData_struct = _getImageInfo(dirlist_qry.directory & variables.separator & dirlist_qry.name) />
                    <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Height", imageData_struct.height, true) />
                    <cfset structInsert(currData_struct.Properties, "Width", imageData_struct.width, true) />
                </cfif>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset structInsert(currData_struct, "Preview", request.defaultIcon) />
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfif></cfloop>

    <cfreturn data_arr />
</cffunction>
```

after extensive research I can not find a way to setup a start / end call without incurring even more slowness.  I know I can not be the only person who has dealt with this, so I wanted to post this for ideas.  Every pagination plugin I tried, did not work because of how core5 is setup, and even then, the cfdirectory struct process can take forever.  Happy Holidays everyone.

Comment: Dies you folder only contain images? I don't know what _isImage() does but if it's expensive, you could filter by file extension, which may be faster. Also, your current implementation of _getDirectoryInfo() doesn't appear to be filtering for safe directories, so could be a security hole, in that it'll allow an attacker to guess directories and get their content listed. That may be elsewhere in your code, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Also, have you compared the time taken in the ajax call, vs the time taken to update the DOM? I'd expect all the time to be in the CF/AJAX, but as you mention it slowing more for IE users, then it could be to do with how you update the DOM?

Comment: they are only images and users can only UL images.  I was hoping/thinking adding lazy loading could be very beneficial, but that may not be the case.  The functions do not appear to be slowing it down that much past the cfdirectory call.

Answer (score 0):

Are your files stored in Windows OS? If so, are you nesting directories or are all images stored in a central directory? I've found slowness creeps in over time when it is just a solitary directory holding all files.

Store files in a date based convention, eg. /year/month/day

Comment: yep, they are stored by type i.e. /email or /event  - I am thinking that we may have to nest them into folders :(